# How to add a character to the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, language-support, character-set

I would like to know if there is a way to add a character to my keyboard, since I have a German keyboard, but my mother language is Spanish and I would like to be able to use the letter "ñ" easily.

Alt+n, Ctl+n (Strg+n), AltGr+n, Alt+Mayus+n, Ctl+Mayus+n (Strg+Mayus+n), AltGr+Mayus+n, none of them work.

I also saw some people changing the keys with xmodmap -e "keycode #=Letter", but I think that if I do that, I am going to delete the letter "n" and get only "ñ", since the keycode I get in xev for "n" is  57 and it registers Alt as another event (64).

If is possible, I would like to be able to add it by pressing Alt+n and Alt+Mayus+n for ñ and Ñ.

Comment: I have set my right Windows key as the compose key. If I press compose then n then shift ~ (tilde) I get ñ. No need to press all at the same time as each keypress latches so can be done in quick succession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` for editing, find the line

```
key <AB06> { [ n, N, rightdoublequotemark, rightsinglequotemark ] };
```

in the *basic* section and replace it with

```
key <AB06> { [ n, N, ntilde, Ntilde ] };
```

With that you can do:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> => ñ

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> => Ñ

But that way `rightdoublequotemark` and `rightsinglequotemark` would be sacrificed. So possibly using a compose key, as suggested in another answer, is better. It depends on your needs.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but I need to map the special character **ə**. The codepoint is `Ctrl+Shift+u+0259`, but I would like to write this special character with my keyboard just by typing `Shift+3`. 

Following the instructions suggested, I have opened the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/it`, then found the right row `key <AE03> { [3, sterling,threesuperior, dead_tilde ]};`

It was'nt work just after substituting `sterling` with `Ctrl+Shift+u+0259`. Where am I wrong? Where else should I set it?

Comment: @nelsonmau: You should simply replace `sterling` with `U0259`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later, you must first download GNOME Tweaks.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Or download from the Ubuntu Software Center if preferred.

Once installed, run it and go to `Keyboard & Mouse` then go to `Keyboard` section.

[image]

and ensure `Right Super` is selected. Best to leave `Left Super` as is since it performs other functions.

That done you will be able to use the right <kbd>Windows</kbd> key to type in special characters on your keyboard.

To type ñ or Ñ do the following in succession (no need to complete the key presses together)
<kbd>Compose Key</kbd> then <kbd>n</kbd> (or <kbd>N</kbd>) then <kbd>~</kbd>.